# ValidateServerCertificate - ServerCertificateValidationCallback

Tags: vb.net, ssl

I am using the below code for certificate validation.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf ValidateServerCertificate)

Public Shared Function ValidateServerCertificate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal certificate As X509Certificate, ByVal chain As X509Chain, ByVal sslPolicyErrors As Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
    If sslPolicyErrors = Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None Then
        Return True
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

I am getting RemoteCertificateChainErrors. How to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback isn't doing anything different to the system default validation. The value of sslPolicyErrors will give an indication as to what the failure is, and you can query the properties of the certificate, chain and sender to decide whether you want to override the failure by returning true.